# iOS UIWebView PDF Not Showing First Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIWebView` where I'm placing a PDF.

The issue I'm facing is when I click on a table cell to show the PDF it does not show the first time however if i go back to the table and click on the cell again it appears.

I call the PDF to get loaded using the following:

```
if ([indexPath row] == 2)
{
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFirstPdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webViewVC.webView loadRequest:request];
        webViewVC.parent = _parent;
        [_parent pushViewController:webViewVC];

}
```

The `webViewVC` itself I allocate using an `initWithNib` which has the `UIWebView` - nothing fancy there, simply a `UIWebView` with a `IBOutlet`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try 2 things:

**(1)** First, try loading the PDF from the web view controller. This is really the standard way to do this, rather than doing a load request for a web view that is not even on screen yet. All outlets are guaranteed to be loaded only in `viewDidLoad` of the controller.

**(2)** Second, try making use of the `UIWebViewDelegate`. For example, you could call `setNeedsDisplay` on the web view once loading is finished.

Comment: Awesome number 1 fixed!

Answer (score 0):

My idea : the first time you try the action your "webViewVC" hasn't been loaded yet, so webViewVC.webView is nil

the second time as you have displayed the webViewVC in your first attempt, it has been loaded, so webViewVC.webView isn't nil;

create a property on your webViewVC where you will set your request

and on your webViewVC viewWillAppear method do your [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];

Comment: Thanks - as above and like you said I need a property in the webViewVC that handled the request rather than setting it where the tableView was!